# C# losing precision thus making equation result 0

Tags: c#, double, precision

I've got a problem with precision. I am multiplying a lot of really low numbers like `0.000001` by each other a lot of times (sometime around `500-1000`) and thus I am losing precision. I've got my numbers in `double` (in dictionary as well).

Is there a way to fix this?
Here is the code:

```
foreach (var word in fileDictionary)
{
    dictionaryTotal.TryGetValue(word.Key, out percent);
    temp = percent;
    A *= temp;
    B *= (1 - temp);
}
```

`A/B` becomes `0.0` in this example.

Comment: Try using `Decimal`.

Comment: @RonBeyer can I put double into decimal? (`temp = percent`)

Comment: No, but you can cast it to decimal temp = (decimal)percent

Comment: @RonBeyer: That won't necessarily help - it's not like `decimal` has infinite precision. It has *more* precision than `double`, but not infinite...

Comment: OP, can you be a bit clearer about exactly what you're doing and what you're trying to achieve? Just how small are you expecting the values to be, after all the multiplications?

Comment: Yes... every built-in data type for storing numbers will have a min/max range so finding a solution depends on what your minimum number will be.  Check this out to see if `decimal` might meet your needs as @RonBeyer suggested: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cs7y5x0x%28v=vs.90%29.aspx.

Comment: @JonSkeet like 0,0001 ^500, also decimal won't work here because Pow doesn't accept decimal..

Comment: [number](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=0.000126086956521739^500)

Comment: So you'll need to find a data type that can represent numbers that small.

Comment: ...or implement one your own - which isn't funny but doable...

Comment: @JonSkeet yes of course, I suppose an easier method would be to create a hybrid type using BigInteger and another BigInteger representing the precision. Store the values as whole numbers along with some representation of the decimal point position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could work with logarithms, and handle the result later as you need.

```
foreach (var word in fileDictionary)
{
    dictionaryTotal.TryGetValue(word.Key, out percent);

    temp = percent;

    A += Math.Log10(temp);
    B += Math.Log10(1 - temp);
}
```

You could then operate the resulting logarithms, instead of the resulting numbers.

Comment: Any particular reason to suggest base 10 rather than natural logarithm?

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan It would work with natural logarithm too, but I guess it could be useful to operate with base10, as I think about a double as a number with a few siginificant digits multiplied by a power of 10. So if you still need to operate the results A and B, you could handle the operation as 2 parts, one for the significant part and another part for the exponent of 10.

Comment: C# double is IEEE 754 64-bit **binary** floating point, in which the multiplication is by powers of two, not ten.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan Thanks to your comment, I studied it a bit more just to learn. It seems that using base2 logarithms we could work with the exact numbers as stored internally, but if the result is at any point back to base10... And we need to use Log(x) for base 'e' or natural logarithm, Log10(x) for base10 or 'human' logarithm, or Log(x, 2) for base 2. Do you think it would be some difference?

Comment: If there is any observable difference in performance, I would use the fastest. Otherwise, I don't think it matters - I was just curious about whether there was some actual advantage to using Log10.

Answer (score 0):

If you expect the final A/B result to be outside the double magnitude range, the best solution is to use logarithms as suggested in a [prior answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30278035/1798593).

If `temp` varies, you do not need A or B, and the final A/B result is expected to be the double range, or can be treated as zero if it is not, you may be able to get it by working directly on the ratio:

```
ratio = ratio * temp / (1 - temp)
```